# ZeroMQ DEALER doesnt receive response from ROUTER in DEALER/ROUTER configuration

Tags: java, sockets, zeromq, distributed-system

Im trying to implement a distributed system in Java using ZeroMQ. I have created a ServerNode and a Broker class. The relevant part of the ServerNode is the following:

```
public class ServerNode {
    ...
    private final ZMQ.Socket dealerSocket;
    private final ConsistentHashing consistentHashing;
    ...

    public ServerNode(String serverAddress, String brokerAddress) {
        this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
        this.brokerAddress = brokerAddress;

        this.context = new ZContext();

        this.dealerSocket = context.createSocket(SocketType.DEALER);
        this.dealerSocket.bind(serverAddress.substring(0, serverAddress.length() - 1) + "1"); //binds to port 5001
        ...
    }

    public void start() {
        joinRing();
        executorService.submit(this::checkNeighbourHeatbeat);
        executorService.submit(this::listenForMessages);

    }

    private void joinRing() {
        ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
        msg.addString("JOIN");
        msg.addString(this.serverAddress);
        
        ZMQ.Socket brokerSocket = context.createSocket(SocketType.DEALER);
        brokerSocket.connect(brokerAddress);
        msg.send(brokerSocket);

        ZMsg response = ZMsg.recvMsg(brokerSocket); //not sure if this is correct
        System.out.println("RECEIVED RESPONSE: " + response);
        if (response != null) {
            String ringState = response.popString();
            this.ring = utils.stringToTreeMap(ringState);
            System.out.println("Received ring state: " + this.ring);
            
            ZMQ.Socket nodeDealerSocket = context.createSocket(SocketType.DEALER);
            for (String nodeAddress : this.ring.values()) {
                if (!Objects.equals(nodeAddress, this.serverAddress)) {
                    nodeDealerSocket.connect(nodeAddress.substring(0, nodeAddress.length() - 1) + "1");
                    msg.send(nodeDealerSocket);
                    nodeDealerSocket.disconnect(nodeAddress.substring(0, nodeAddress.length() - 1) + "1");
                }
            }
            nodeDealerSocket.close();
            
        }
        brokerSocket.close();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String serverAddress;
        String brokerAddress = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5000";

        if (args.length > 0) {
            serverAddress = args[0];
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid server address (e.g., tcp://127.0.0.2:5000): ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            serverAddress = scanner.nextLine();
            scanner.close();
        }

        ServerNode node = new ServerNode(serverAddress, brokerAddress);
        node.start();
    }
    ...
}
```

And the Broker:

```
public class Broker {

    private ConsistentHashing consistentHashing;
    private ZContext context;
    private ZMQ.Socket serverRoutSocket; // REP socket for "JOIN" requests
    private TreeMap<Integer, String> ring;

    public Broker() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        this.consistentHashing = new ConsistentHashing(1);
        this.context = new ZContext();

        this.serverRoutSocket = context.createSocket(SocketType.ROUTER);
        this.serverRoutSocket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");

        this.ring = new TreeMap<>();
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("BROKER STARTED");
        Poller poller = context.createPoller(1); //! LATEr ADD ROUTER CLIENT
        poller.register(serverRoutSocket, Poller.POLLIN);

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            poller.poll();

            if (poller.pollin(0)) { 
                ZMsg serverRoutReq = ZMsg.recvMsg(serverRoutSocket);
                if (serverRoutReq != null) {
                    handleServerRoutRequest(serverRoutReq);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleServerRoutRequest(ZMsg request) {
        System.out.println("REQUEST: " + request);
        String dealerIdentity = request.popString();
        String header = request.popString();
        String server = null;
        ZMsg response = new ZMsg();
        System.out.println("identity: " + dealerIdentity);
        response.addString(dealerIdentity);

        switch (header) {
            case "JOIN" -> {
                server = request.popString();
                consistentHashing.addServer(server, ring);
                response.addString(ring.toString());
                System.out.println("RESPONSE SENT: " + response);
                response.send(serverRoutSocket);
            }
            case "REMOVE" -> {
                System.out.println("SERVER REMOVED: " + ring);
                server = request.popString();
                consistentHashing.removeServer(server, ring);
            }
            default -> {
            }
            //ignore
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Broker broker = new Broker();
            broker.start();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the joinRing method of the ServerNode class I connect the DEALER socket to the Broker's ROUTER socket. I then send a message composed of "JOIN" and then the server address which is then received by the broker and handled accoridngly in the handleServerRoutRequest method. The broker should then respond to the server with the current ring state which the server will use to find all the nodes present in the system. After that the server simply sends a join message to each node so that they can update their own ring.

After sending the join request to the broker I expected that the broker would return the ring, and while the message appears to be created correctly with the identity followed by the load (ex: [ 00C1D76C28, {1114376065=tcp://127.0.0.2:5000} ]), the server gets stuck on the `ZMsg response = ZMsg.recvMsg(brokerSocket);` line. Why is the response not being received?

Answer (score 0):

Java's 0MQ interface is not the best. I've used C++'s and Python's interface, which works well.
Also, looking at your code I can tell it is pretty clean and not convoluted at all, which leads me to assume it's not your fault.
Have you tried contacting 0MQ's support? I heard they have a pretty good hotline you can call during work hours and they might be able to help you with your problems.
If that doesn't work out, I'd recommend you use [java.nio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) for any socket-related work while doing it java.
By the way, is there any particular reason for choosing Java here? It's like shooting yourself in the foot, seeing as there are many better solutions such as PHP, Perl or VBA.

Comment: Sadly I'm kinda forced to use it as it's for a university assignment, truthfully its the first time I'm using ZeroMQ but it was recommended by the professor.

Comment: The post doesn't answer the initial question. It's more opinion the a solution. IMHO Such posts should be a comments (not answers).